# SQL select query where all rows must have an equal value

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to generate a bill from a list of orders.

I have a query where I get all orders that have not been paid yet (paid_date = null), but the problem is that some orders have different tax codes. Now I can only combine orders with the same tax code in that query.

I was thinking about something like below, but this obviously does not work:

```
SELECT * from orders 
WHERE paid_date IS NULL AND tax_code = MAX(tax_code);
```

Almost like an inverse Distinct.

UPDATE:
Sorry, I guess the question was not clear. I'm not looking for the tax code. I'm looking for a list of orders that all have the same tax code. But I don't care which code it is. This is really just a security measure, normally all tax codes are the same, but in rare cases they are different. In that case the user needs to generate 2 separate bills.

Any simple ideas?

Comment: This is likely a variation of the 'greatest-n-per-group' problem. I have updated the tags to reflect this. Hopefully there are some useful associated question links as a result. MySQL, unfortunately, absolutely sucks for this type of query.

Comment: It is not clear what output is desired. If you have four tax codes, what should your query return? Are you going to pass in a requested tax code? Should they simply sort the orders by tax code? Are you trying to get the sum total of orders with the same tax code? If so, is the total of the order stored in the Orders table or somewhere else (like OrderLineItems).

Comment: It still isn't clear. "All orders that have the same tax code" simply implies `Select ... From Orders Where tax_code = 'foo'`. We are presuming that each row in the Orders table represents a single order. Is it that in your design an "order" can span multiple rows in the Orders table?

Comment: I think I was looking for something simple that does not exist. I will go with the solution from David and run two queries. 
Thanks to all for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to identify another column that is consistent aside from tax code, for example, perhaps customer_ID (for example);

Get a list of tax_codes for the current customer:

```
SELECT customer_ID, tax_code
FROM Orders
WHERE customer_ID = 'some customer ID'
GROUP BY customer_ID, tax_code
```

The above query will return the number of distinct rows, so if there are 2 tax_codes;
Then you get 2 rows, and need to generate 2 bills;

Then you can query as others have shown:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE paid_date IS NULL
AND tax_code = 'first tax code from your first query'
```

This will involve multiple trips to DB. Or you can write a stored procedure, utilize temp tables, and return multiple sets (multiple SELECT statements), each set containing a tabular list of orders by tax_code.

Alternately if you are using SQL (don't know about MySQL) you can write SQL XML query which will return hierarchical data by customer_id and tax_code.

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the original query, a subquery would do it:

```
SELECT * from orders 
 WHERE paid_date IS NULL 
   AND tax_code = (
       select max(tax_code)
         from orders
        where paid_date is null
   )
```

Comment: Yep, that would work. 
The problem is that the real query is a bit more complex, so the subquery would be equally complex too. So I was hoping there is something easier?

Answer (score 0):

You should order by `tax_code` and will get the list of orders ordered by `tax_code`:

```
select * from orders
  where paid_date is null
 order by tax_code
```

Then iterate your results. Whenever you have a distinct `tax_code` generate a new bill.

A `group_concat` might give you what you want:

```
select tax_code, group_concat(order_id order by order_id) from orders
  where paid_date is null
 group by tax_code
-- optionally you can use a LIMIT 1 if you just want orders for the first tax_code
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea, but actually I was looking more for a query that would just returns all orders that have the same tax code. And then the user just has to create a second bill manually.

Comment: Take a look at `group_concat` I just added.

Comment: @Remy - If you are going to pass in a tax code, then wouldn't the obvious work: `Select ... From Orders Where TaxCode = 'some passed value'`

Comment: @Thomas: I think he wants just the first tax_code (doesn't matter what value it is).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I arbitrarily picked a tax_code from the list of Orders since you did not provide us any detail about how the selected tax_code would be picked.

```
Select ..
From Orders As O
    Join    (
            Select O1.tax_code
            From Orders As O1
            Limit 1
            ) As Z
        On Z.tax_code = O.tax_code
Where paid_date Is Null
```

The problem here is that the subquery might find the tax_code associated with only one order where as the vast majority of orders are associated with another tax_code. Another solution which finds the "most common" tax code would be:

```
Select ..
From Orders As O
    Join    (
            Select O1.tax_code
            From Orders As O1
            Group By O1.tax_code
            Order By Count(*) Desc
            Limit 1
            ) As Z
        On Z.tax_code = O.tax_code
Where paid_date Is Null
```